# SmartGWT dynamic columns in ListGrid (client side)

Tags: java, grails, smartgwt

I would like to create a ListGrid where the user can add columns to define some values row per column, just like an excel sheet. Adding values vertically should be as simple as vertically. I'm pretty new in web developing and I count on more experienced friends.
I'm using SmartGWT together with grails framework so I don't need SmartGWT server since it costs a lot of money. So the type of datasource I'm using is RestDataSource. But there is the limitation that it cannot be modified dynamically.

As I searched the web for a solution, I saw that the smartGWT EE can do things such as providing xml datasource, which can be modified per request. Does someone have a clue how to achieve this effect without using commercial solutions like smartgwt server? I can even change the technology in the project just to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/sourcegen/grid/databinding/GridDataBindingInlineDataSample.java.html#) for [Grids > Data Binding > Inline Data](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_databinding_inline_data) it looks like you can easily use any custom format from the server. Just create a `ListGridRecord[]` array and set that as the data with `listGrid.setData()`. Looks pretty straightforward so I'm not sure why you would need a commercial solution such as SmartGWT server for this simple requirement.

Comment: Anyway I need some connection to database. Do you know how the datasource might look like for this? I think it should be packed into one field on the controller side and datasource should have only one field. Then I could parse the commas to divide fields for each column. Does it make any sense? :)

Comment: I believe SmartGWT is a good solution for something like this.  In my experience, pure GWT is much more finicky and difficult to control.  SmartGWT has a larger number of free-to-use features than is offered by GWT and based on their large number of high-profile customers, it doesn't seem likely that the company that provides SmartGWT (Isomorphic software) is going anywhere.